# How can I grep for text in specific file names under a specific directory structure recursively?

Tags: search, terminal, grep, directory, pattern-matching

I have a directory, with thousands of other directories, each of which contains a consistent directory structure along with a specific file name I want to grep in for a pattern of text.

Let's say I have from my root DIR where I will be initiating the grep, directories like this:

```
/
   /dir1
      /etc
        /net
          /file.properties
   /dir2
      /etc
        /net
          /file.properties
```

I want search across all the directories dir1, dir2, etc, for a text pattern in all file.properties files that fall under the path "*/etc/net/file.properties"

What would my grep command look like to search all dir1, dir2...dirN for my pattern in file.properties under the path structure I specified?

What I have now is:

```
grep -r "text here" --include='*/net/etc/file.properties' .
```

Comment: Do you have to use grep only ? Can't you find all file.properties files and then grep from that result set ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious answer would seem to be `grep "text here" */etc/net/file.properties`. Are there too many directories for this to work?
If so, you might be able to do something like

```
for dir in *; do
    if [ -f "$dir/net/etc/file.properties" ]; then
        echo "$dir/net/etc/file.properties"
    fi
done | xargs grep "text here"
```

Comment: This works, but it does not restrict the grep search to files ONLY under that path structure. I know this because through out the search grep outputs warnings like ./dir1234/var/log: No such file or directory.

Comment: The string "`/var`" hasn't appeared in this thread until now. Do you know where it's coming from?

Answer (score 0):

find . -name "file.properties" | grep "/etc/net/file.properties" | xargs grep "text here"